# Checkboxes: How can I check two sets at the same time?

Tags: javascript, php, html, checkbox

I have 2 sets of checkboxes in my webpage, and I have a small script that is checking the boxes and not the others when I click one, which is what I want.

Unfortunately, it only checks one set of boxes, and leaves the other set unchecked.

Although on reloading my page both sets are checked, this is due to my post variable. I will show you the code.

Can anybody see where I could update it to check both boxes when clicking one box?

```
<div id='checkbox-container'>
    <input type="checkbox" id="small" name="displaytypethumbs"  value="minlist" <?php if (!empty($_POST['displaytypethumbs'])): ?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> onclick="chbx(this)">
    <label for="small" class="smalllistings">Thumbs</label>
    </input>

    <input type="checkbox" id="large"  name="displaytypegallery"  value="maxlist" <?php if (!empty($_POST['displaytypegallery'])): ?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> onclick="chbx(this)">
    <label for="large" class="largelistings" >Gallery</label>   
    </input>

    <input type="checkbox" id="fulllistings"  name="displaytypefull"  value="fulllist" <?php if (!empty($_POST['displaytypefull'])): ?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?>onclick="chbx(this)">
    <label for="fulllistings" class="fulllistings" >Full Listing</label>    
    </input>
</div>
<div id='checkbox-container2'>
  <input type="checkbox" id="small2" name="displaytypethumbs"  value="minlist"  class="smalllistingsbox" 
  <?php if (!empty($_POST['displaytypethumbs'])): ?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> onclick="chbx(this)">
    <label for="small2" class="smalllistingsmain" >Thumbs</label>
  </input>

  <input type="checkbox" id="large2"  name="displaytypegallery"  value="maxlist" class="largelistingsbox"  
  <?php if (!empty($_POST['displaytypegallery'])): ?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> onclick="chbx(this)">
    <label for="large2" class="largelistingsmain" >Gallery</label>  
  </input>

  <input type="checkbox" id="fulllistings2"  name="displaytypefull"  value="fulllist" 
  <?php if (!empty($_POST['displaytypefull'])): ?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> onclick="chbx(this)">   
    <label for="fulllistings2" class="fulllistingsmain"  >Full Listings</label> 
     </input>
  </div>
</form>
<script>
function chbx(obj) {
   var that = obj;
   if(document.getElementById(that.id).checked == true) {
     document.getElementById('small').checked = false;
     document.getElementById('large').checked = false;
     document.getElementById('fulllistings').checked = false;
     document.getElementById('small2').checked = false;
     document.getElementById('large2').checked = false;
     document.getElementById('fulllistings2').checked = false;    
     document.getElementById(that.id).checked = true;
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: he meant javascript

Comment: Your `chbx` function will only uncheck your boxes. It does not set checked to true.

Comment: $_POST or $_SESSION ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, i should of thought about it before posting really, i chose the simple method . Very wet, But still did the job... Thanks for your help guys.

```
<div id='checkbox-container'>

    <input type="checkbox" id="small" name="displaytypethumbs"  value="minlist"  <?php if (!empty($_POST['displaytypethumbs'])):  ?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> onclick="chbx(this); check1();">
    <label for="small" class="smalllistings">Thumbs</label>
    </input>

    <input type="checkbox" id="large"  name="displaytypegallery"  value="maxlist" <?php if (!empty($_POST['displaytypegallery'])): ?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> onclick="chbx(this); check2();">
    <label for="large" class="largelistings" >Gallery</label>   
    </input>

    <input type="checkbox" id="fulllistings"  name="displaytypefull"  value="fulllist" <?php if (!empty($_POST['displaytypefull'])): ?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?>onclick="chbx(this); check3();">
    <label for="fulllistings" class="fulllistings" >Full Listing</label>    
    </input>

</div>

<div id='checkbox-container'>

<input type="checkbox" id="small2" name="displaytypethumbs"  value="minlist"  class="smalllistingsbox" 
<?php if (!empty($_POST['displaytypethumbs'])): ?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> onclick="chbx(this); check4();">
<label for="small2" class="smalllistingsmain" >Thumbs</label>
</input>


<input type="checkbox" id="large2"  name="displaytypegallery"  value="maxlist" class="largelistingsbox"  
<?php if (!empty($_POST['displaytypegallery'])): ?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> onclick="chbx(this); check5();">
<label for="large2" class="largelistingsmain" >Gallery</label>  
</input>


<input type="checkbox" id="fulllistings2"  name="displaytypefull"  value="fulllist" 
<?php if (!empty($_POST['displaytypefull'])): ?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> onclick="chbx(this); check6();">   
<label for="fulllistings2" class="fulllistingsmain"  >Full Listings</label> 
</input>


</div>

</form>



<script>
function chbx(obj)
{
var that = obj;
if(document.getElementById(that.id).checked == true) {

document.getElementById('small').checked = false;
document.getElementById('large').checked = false;
document.getElementById('fulllistings').checked = false;


document.getElementById('small2').checked = false;
document.getElementById('large2').checked = false;
document.getElementById('fulllistings2').checked = false;     

document.getElementById(that.id).checked = true;
}
}

function check1(){document.getElementById('small2').checked = true; }
function check2(){document.getElementById('large2').checked = true; }
function check3(){document.getElementById('fulllistings2').checked = true; }


function check4(){document.getElementById('small').checked = true; }
function check5(){document.getElementById('large').checked = true; }
function check6(){document.getElementById('fulllistings').checked = true; }


</script>       
/
```